# allow .bin extension for specific folder and it's subfolders - NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I need to allow .bin extension in specific folder on my server (NGINX)

I have tried to add code below to /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com

```
location /PUZZL/ {
root /var/www/DOMAIN.com/htdocs;
    location ~ \.bin$ {
               allow all;
               access_log off;
               log_not_found off;
              }
       }
}
```

But nginx.service failed to reload than...
However this code below, works, but it works for whole website and I need to allow only one folder with it's subfolders:

```
location ~*^.+\.(bin) {
        root /var/www/domain.com/htdocs/;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
```

Can you, please help to formulate right code for this,
Thank you in advance for any suggestions / help !

Comment: You should test the configuration using `nginx -t` - in your snippet you have an extra closing brace.

Comment: @RichardSmith It's, thank you! my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answere:

```
location /PUZZLS/{
    root /var/www/domain.com/htdocs/;

    location ~*^.+\.(bin) {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
      }
    }
```

works like a charm for me!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**